# Determining which list of integers is greater

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml

I am trying to figure out which list of integers is greater.
The representation of `[1;2;3]` is actually `123`. 
So given two lists of integers, I want to compare each element to determine which number is greater in the end. Returning `1` if `list1 > list2`, `-1` if `list1 < list2`, and `0` if they are equal.
This is what I have so far, but when I try to run it I get errors and I don't understand why. I was also asked to do all recurring in tail recursion form whenever possible. Is this correct tail recursion?

```
let rec compare' list1 list2 currentOrder = match (list1, list2) with
  | [],[]                     -> 0
  | list1, []                 -> 1
  | [], list2                 -> -1
  | car1::cdr1, car2::cdr2    ->      (*car1 contains the current element and cdr1 contains the rest of the list. Ex car1 = [1], cdr2 = [2;3]*)
    let nextCompare = 
        (
            if cdr1 = [] && cdr2 = [] 
            then 0
            else 1
        )                           
    in 
    (
      if (nextCompare != 0)(*To check if we are not at the end of the list*)
      then (      (*Compare the cars to determine the currentOrder and recursively call with the next number*)
        if car1 > car2
        then (compare' (cdr1 cdr2 1))
        else if car1 < car2
        then (compare' (cdr1 cdr2 -1))
        else (compare' cdr1 cdr2 currentOrder)
      )
      else (*we are at the end of the list so we want to return the current order*)
      (   (*Still need to check in case there is only 1 digit number, because we did not update currentOrder for it to be returned*)
        if car1 > car2
        then 1
        else if car1 < car2
        then -1
        else currentOrder
      )
    )


Printf.printf (compare' [1;2;3] [3;2;1] 0)
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @glennsl For the line "(compare' (cdr1 cdr2 1))"    This expression has type 'a list
       This is not a function; it cannot be applied.

Comment: Your problem there is that you have too many parens. You're trying to apply `cdr2` and `1` to `cdr1`, which is going to result in it complaining that you're treating the list `cdr1`as a function :)

Comment: @glennsl When I remove the parentheses to (compare' cdr1 cdr2 -1), I get This expression has type int -> int
       but an expression was expected of type int

Comment: A few lines further down you do the same, but there you also need to wrap `-1` in parens: `(-1)`, otherwise it's ambiguous and will confuse the compiler.

Comment: @glennsl ok thats good to know, didn't know that would be an issue.

Comment: Instead of using `nextCompare` you can do that check in the pattern match: `| car'::[], car2::[] -> ...`. That will make your code a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem you had were some extra parentheses around the arguments of a few function applications (e.g. `(compare' (cdr1 cdr2 1))`) which tells OCaml that you'd like to call `cdr1` with the arguments `cdr2` and `1`, and then apply the result of that to the `compare'`. The compiler will therefore complain that you're trying to use the list `cdr1` as a function. It's a simple mistake to make if you're used to function application with parentheses.

The second problem was that you had `-1` without parentheses, which the compiler will interpret as applying `1` to the binary `-` operator, and therefore complain that the result of that is a function rather than an int, as you'd expect. The reason for this odd behaviour is that OCaml supports partial function application, which causes some ambiguities. Do disambiguate this you just need to surround it in parentheses: `(-1)`.

And finally, there was a fair bit of redundancy in your code, so I've simplified it a bit for you. Less code also means fewer places to screw up, and to look through to find screwups, which is quite convenient when you're learning :)

```
let rec compare' list1 list2 currentOrder =
  match list1, list2 with
  | [], []                     -> currentOrder
  | _, []                     -> 1
  | [], _                     -> -1
  | car1::cdr1, car2::cdr2    ->
    let order =
      if car1 > car2 then 1
      else if car1 < car2 then -1
      else currentOrder
    in
    compare' cdr1 cdr2 order
```

**I give no guarantees that this is logically correct, however, it's just a transformation of what you had written (In fact I know it's not correct, but it's an assignment for a reason).**

Comment: Absolutely amazing simplification of what I wanted to do. However, when I ran it, regarding the line : compare' cdr1 cdr2 order, I get the error  This function has type 'a list -> 'a list -> int -> int
       It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'. What does that mean?

Comment: It probably means you either need to add a `;;` after this function to terminate the top level declaration, or add `let () =` before `Printf.printf ...`. In general you shouldn't put statements directly on the top level, since the compiler isn't able to separate the statement from the previous declaration. It thinks `Printf...` is just another argument to whatever came before.

Comment: Was the logical error you mentioned that it returns the order of the last digit? Ex. If I was comparing 123 and 321, the return value would be 1(given 123 is list1). If that is the case, that there isn't a problem because that was actually what I wanted. My mistake in describing the representation of the number above, [1,2,3] was actually 321, so that it would be simpler for do to math operations from lower order to higher order.

Comment: Ah, yes that was it. There might be other problems too of course, for all I know, but that was the only inconsistency I noticed.

Comment: I got it all to work and run. Thank You so much, I was on this for 4 hrs and I would have been on it for a lot more hours without your help.

Comment: Happy to help! :) Would you mind clicking the checkmark next to the answer, to mark the answer as accepted, and the question as answered? It helps us focus on the questions that haven't been answered yet, and gives us both a few lovely internet points to boot ;)